# Kafka GetOffsetShell timestamp doesn't seem to work

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to look at a Kafka topic starting from a particular time, using `kafka-console-consumer` and passing it an `--offset` corresponding to that time.  In order to figure out what offset to specify, I tried using the command:

```
kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list ... --topic data.live --time 1533827402000
```

but all I get back is:

```
data.live:8:
data.live:2:
data.live:5:
data.live:4:
...
```

(i.e., no offsets).  The command works fine if I specify a `--time` of -2 ("earliest") or -1 ("latest"), giving back results like:

```
data.live:8:765349205
data.live:2:766537956
data.live:5:759575128
data.live:4:761703674
...
```

(I assume that the numbers after the second colons are offsets).

My question is:  How do I get offsets for an intermediate time?   I tried using a millisecond timestamp that I *think* should have some data.

---

And a second question:  Using the offsets for `--time` of -1 and -2, I guess at an intermediate offset, and then I pass that to the

```
 kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server ... --topic data.live --offset 77000000 --partition 1
```

but the `--offset` seems to make no difference in what I get back (my topic values contain a human-readable timestamp that indicates this).

Comment: What version of Kafka are you running?

Comment: INFO Kafka version : 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

When I run `date` on my Mac, here's what I get

```
$ date -r 1533827402000
Fri Jan 20 17:13:20 CST 50575
```

I think it doesn't print the offsets because they don't exist (yet)

Try `--time 1533827402` (which has a year in `2018`, for the same command)

You can also do `kafka-console-consumer ... --property print.timestamp=true`, then `grep` out the first few digits you would be interested in, then use those values as examples for the `GetOffsetShell`

Comment: Tried the shorter (10-digit, seconds) time stamp, but it didn't help.   I'll take your other suggestion and see whether I can find a plausible timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are running with an older log format version?

We are seeing the same thing but we have log.message.format.version=0.9.0.1

I think that is why, log message timestamps weren't introduced until 0.10