# Any Kafka API to delete/retrieve topics not received any new message before date range?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am working on utility to delete kafka topics not being used for somedays. I am able to delete topics using kafka Admin/Consumer Api. My Ask is how to identify when topic has received last message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GetOffsetShell` tool/class to list beginning and ending offsets of topics.. If they match, topic is empty. You can also get offsets for a specific timestamp (for Kafka versions 0.10.2+, I think)

Or you can SSH to the brokers and iterate the log directories / dump log segments to see if they are empty / filter them by time.

Neither approach will guarantee that any producer will be actively connecting to the topic you're trying to delete and trying to send a message, which would invalidate your search

Comment: I am also looking for solution on this, when I try to get offset by timestamp, I get null values. That could be due to either there is no offset for greater than equal to the timestamp or may be topic is newly created within that timeframe. How can I get the offset for the specified timestamp and compare it with latest offset in order to delete the topic?

Comment: I was under the assumption that the next available offsets would be returned, but maybe not. [Related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51934023/kafka-getoffsetshell-timestamp-doesnt-seem-to-work). You can also use `offsetsForTimes` - https://kafka.apache.org/28/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html